# EMACS custom-indention function for a symbol rather than a symbolic expression?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, indentation

CLIPS and JESS are lispy languages used for AI and rules-engines. Their EMACS are derived from lisp-mode. The most important form to format correctly is defrule, it helps for readability. By default the normal lisp-mode formatting is used like this:

```
(defrule any-foo
  "This is a rule for any-foo."
  ?f <- (foo)
  =>
  (do-something-to ?f))
```

The desired formatting would be like this with the optional documentation 2 chars in and the right arrow two chars in and everything else 6 chars in like this:

```
(defrule any-foo
  "This is a rule for any-foo."
      ?f <- (foo)
  =>
      (do-something-to ?f))
```

There are a lot of resources out there about custom indentation in EMACS, but [this](http://community.schemewiki.org/?emacs-indentation) one jumped out because it made wonder if I could just intercept the formatting of anything matching the right arrow and intercepting that. When I read further, I understood it more like you may write a custom formatting function for a symbolic expression, but, the right arrow is not that. I don't want to write a formatting function for the whole top level, and am not sure how yet any way.

What is the right way to get this desired formatting style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the indentation for a Lisp form whose first element is SYMBOL by giving SYMBOL a `lisp-indent-function` property. See the "[Lisp Indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Indent.html)" section in the Emacs manual. This property can take various kinds of value, which are documented in the "[Indenting Macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Indenting-Macros.html#Indenting-Macros)" section of the Emacs Lisp manual. In particular, if you set the property to be a symbol, then:

> symbol should be a function name; that function is called to calculate the indentation of a line within this expression. The function receives two arguments:
>
> **state**
>   The value returned by `parse-partial-sexp` (a Lisp primitive for indentation and nesting computation) when it parses up to the beginning of this line.
>
> **pos** The position at which the line being indented begins.
>
> It should return either a number, which is the number of columns of indentation for that line, or a list whose car is such a number. The difference between returning a number and returning a list is that a number says that all following lines at the same nesting level should be indented just like this one; a list says that following lines might call for different indentations.

(The function actually receives these arguments in the other order; I [submitted a bug report](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=13450) suggesting that the manual be corrected, and this was fixed in Emacs 24.3.)

So, you need to write a function that calculates the appropriate indentation for a line within a `defrule` form, perhaps like this:

```
(defun indent-for-defrule (pos state)
  "A lisp-indent-function for defrule.
Indent docstring and => by 2 columns; other lines by 6 columns."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char pos)
    (let* ((have-string (looking-at "\\s-*\""))
           (have-arrow (looking-at "\\s-*=>"))
           (first-sexp (progn
                         (ignore-errors (backward-sexp))
                         (<= (point) (nth 2 state)))))
      (+ (progn (goto-char (nth 1 state)) (current-column))
         (if (or (and first-sexp have-string) have-arrow) 2 6)))))
```

And then assign that function to the `lisp-indent-function` property of the `defrule` symbol:

```
(put 'defrule 'lisp-indent-function #'indent-for-defrule)
```